# Nexus 5X bootloop, recovery mode doesn't exist

Tags: recovery-mode, boot-loop, nexus-5x

Yesterday my Nexus 5x froze and  started bootlooping, it did start twice since yesterday but only for a couple of minutes. I tried going into the recovery mode, but as soon as I click the power button to enter the recovery mode, it goes back to bootloop. Also tried going into safe mode once, but that didn't help.

I have already tried flashing the device with the Nexus root toolkit, but the problem still exists.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue right now, I did all the steps successfully from here, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz6x7k-VkpUJam5Mc1hKa09PVGc/view were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

[TechTimes reports](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/186940/20161125/lg-cant-fix-nexus-5x-bootloop-issue-so-its-offering-full-refunds.htm) that:

> LG is currently unable to repair Nexus 5X smartphones affected by a so-called "bootloop" malfunction, so it's issuing full refunds to make up for it.

so I don't think there's anything you can do to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today.
I tried multiple times to

- re-flash TWRP
- flash older versions of TWRP
- flash older versions of the factory image (without the internal storage part)
- flash the latest factory image (without the internal storage part)

Nothing changed, but **this procedure worked for me (only once)**:

1. Start the phone in `fastboot` mode
2. On the PC, rename latest TWRP in `recovery.img` (I think it isn't required, but that's what I did)
3. On the PC

   ```
   fastboot boot recovery.img
   ```

I backed up everything I needed from the internal storage (via `adb`) and then rebooted the phone.

I was expecting to do a full wipe, but everything started as usual.

EDIT: Sadly this procedure works every now and then. I noticed that leaving the phone boot loop, for example during the night, brings it back to a bootable state, but if you reboot the device the boot loop sequence starts again.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of screaming and shouting (not really), I finally found a fix.

There are some boot images out there that should fix it, but in my case they didn't. So I decided to find a way and apply the fix myself.

**You'll probably lose all your data with this**

I used Ubuntu 18.04 for this. Since one of the packages I used required Linux and I'm not hipster enough to buy a Mac.

Since applying the fix yourself requires you to unpack en repack the boot image, I used the GIT repository at https://github.com/cfig/Android_boot_image_editor.

They tested it with the original Nexus 5x factory image, so I decided to download it (MDA89E). (https://developers.google.com/android/images#bullhead)

Step 1. Download Factory Image and unpack it (**also unpack the zip file within in (containing the actual factory image**)

Step 2. Acquire the Android Platform Tools.

```
sudo apt install android-sdk
```

Step 3. Acquire Java

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

Step 4. Clone the repository mentioned above

```
git clone https://github.com/cfig/Android_boot_image_editor.git --depth=1
```

Step 5. Follow the instructions! (You'll need Android Studio too)

Step 6. Open the bootimg.json file and make sure the following commands are present in the info > cmdline value.

```
"cmdline" : "console={** other commands are here **} androidboot.hardware=bullhead boot_cpus=0-3 maxcpus=4 cpu_max_a53=1632000 cpu_max_a57=0",
```

The `boot_cpus` command is probably already present. change its value to `0-3` and make sure the `maxcpus=4`, `cpu_max_a53=1632000` `cpu_max_a57=0` are present.

Step 7. Repack your image (Follow instructions!)

```
sudo ./gradlew pack
```

Step 8. Move the boot.img.signed file to the unpacked factory image **(The actual image mentioned in step 1)**. So you should overwrite the existing boot.img with the newly packed boot.img.signed (rename it to boot.img and throw away the original)

Step 9. Start ADB server (Maybe reconnect your devices afterwards)

```
adb devices
```

Step 10. Make sure your device is connected and visible for 'fastboot devices'. That means it should be in the fastboot mode (Power button + Volume down while booting)

Step 11. **Let's go!** (All these files are (now) present in the freshly downloaded factory image.

```
fastboot unlock flashing
fastboot erase userdate

fastboot flash bootloader {bootloader-image.img}
fastboot reboot bootloader
fastboot flash radio {radio-image.img}
fastboot reboot bootloader
```

Step 12. Flash the rest

```
fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot flash cache cache.img
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot flash system system.img
fastboot flash userdata userdata.img
fastboot flash vendor vendor.img
fastboot reboot
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use adb from pc, with the prompt commands