# Cannot unlock Nexus 5X due to bootloop

Tags: boot-loop, lg, nexus-5x

My phone is in a boot loop. It shows the Google text and restarts after few seconds. Not even the animation starts. It is the same if I start recovery mode.

I have windows 10, "Android ADB Interface" driver from Google and the phone shows up in device manager when i connect when the phone is in the bootloader screen (power + down).

I only can communicate with the phone when it is on the bootloader screen. For `fastboot devices` the phone shows up but not for `adb devices`. I tried all my usb ports.

`DEVICE STATE - locked` and unlocking from OEM is disabled.

I tried to connect to LGUP in Download Mode (power + up) with no success it doesn't recognise the phone.

I tried to unlock with Nexus Root Toolkit but it restarting my device and waiting for it but it restarts before the program recognizing it.

If I could make it work with LGUP or I could unlock somehow I could flash it with an image what can disable the big cores so the bootloop probably goes away.

I don't mind losing data. Any advice?

Comment: When you have a probably working image and a working fastboot why don't you flash the image via fastboot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nexus 5X bootloop, recovery mode doesn't exist](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/169547/nexus-5x-bootloop-recovery-mode-doesnt-exist)